# passing php variable to javascript

Tags: javascript

I.ve this thing in php

```
$v = "test";
```

How do i pass this to javascript

I did like this

```
 <script>
  var t = <?php echo $v; ?>
 </script>
```

I'm passing that **t** to URL
 But ii says undefined

Comment: Please mark the answer, np helping.

Comment: Isn't this question asked on a daily basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
 var t = "<?php echo $v; ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of the page in your browser (with your first attempt), you see:

```
<script>
 var t = test
</script>
```

And from here, you could guess what's amiss.

Comment: +1. The only answer to help the OP help himself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <script>
  var t = '<?php echo $v; ?>';
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var t = '$v';</script>";
?>
```

Javascript runs clientside and php runs server side so you can't just pass one straight through to the other - they don't run at the same time. You can use php to create javascript to run later though.